# RuntimeError during processing .jpg file (exception 20) retrain inceptionV3 tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

My system setup
OS: Ubuntu 16.04LTS
GPU: GTX1060
tensorflow version: tensorflow-gpu (1.6.0)

I am trying to retrain the inceptionV3 classifier model which I trained on MSCeleb-1M dataset using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py.

then I tried to retrain using custom images and classes with https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py.

I have noticed that the script is for an outdated inceptionV3 architecture hence I have modified the bottleneck tensor and input tensor names to match the nodes of my retrained inceptionV3 model. However when feeding own images into the retrain script, I keep hitting this error

```
INFO:tensorflow:Creating bottleneck at /home/m360/MachineLearning/models/msceleb-small-inception-v3/bottleneck/tulips/5524946579_307dc74476.jpg_inception_v3.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1486, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 1187, in main
bottleneck_tensor, FLAGS.architecture)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 500, in cache_bottlenecks
resized_input_tensor, bottleneck_tensor, architecture)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 442, in get_or_create_bottleneck
bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 397, in create_bottleneck_file
str(e)))
RuntimeError: Error during processing file /home/m360/MachineLearning/my_dataset/flower_photos/tulips/5524946579_307dc74476.jpg (20)
```

I do not understand where has gone wrong as there is no documentation about this specific exception code anywhere online so far I have searched. I am thinking it might be problems with the decode_jpeg function in the script but could not crack my head around it.

Please help to enlighten me. Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like one of the jpgs is corrupted. Can you add logging to see which one?

Comment: it doesnt seem like there is problem with building image data from decode_jpeg function but failed at the stage of bottleneck_creation. it seems like there is issue with my resized_input_tensor.  however im not able to determine which is the correct node for input. by inspecting the graph_def i figure it would be distort_image/Mul or

Comment: Try new tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining